# Pandas to match with str.contains and inverse of str.contains for another columns

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking forward to use `str.contains` for one column and for another just inverse of it `~ str.contains` in pandas.

The First one is `OS Version` column where i'm using `str.contains` and that's fine, However, I'm conjointly looking for another column `Aux Site` where this column ignore or do not match for string `VCAD`.

Saying that, i don't want to remove `VCAD` selection from the `Aux Site` column so that each matched row can be removed or not picked up.

1) the First one which is fine ..

```
df1['OS Version'].str.contains(MATCH_PATT)
```

2 - the second One with inverse match as follows

```
df1[~df1['Aux Site'].str.contains('VCAD')]
```

Here i mean to match the `MATCH_PATT` for given column `OS Version` , whereas if it finds string/ pattern VCAD in the `Aux Site` column then remove that or skip it.

### Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

MATCH_PATT = "AIX|CentOS|Fedora|RHEL|SunOS|SuSE|Ubuntu|(?<!\?)\?(?!\?)"
COLUMN_NAMES = ['Hostname', 'IP Address', 'Aux Site', 'OS Version']
df1 = pd.read_csv('/home/karn/plura/Test/Python_Panda/CyberArk/host.txt', delimiter = "\t", usecols=COLUMN_NAMES, encoding='cp1252',  dtype='unicode')
df2 = df1[df1['OS Version'].str.contains(MATCH_PATT,  na=False)][['Hostname', 'IP Address', 'Aux Site', 'OS Version']]
df2[['Hostname', 'Aux Site']] = df2[['Hostname', 'Aux Site']].replace({'\*': ''}, regex=True)
df2.to_csv('new_survey_list-1', index=False)
```

### Possible Solution:

```
df1[(df1['OS Version'].str.contains(MATCH_PATT,  na=False)) & (~df1['Aux Site'].str.contains('VCAD'))] [['Hostname', 'IP Address', 'Aux Site', 'OS Version']]
```

I'm assuming the above solution with `&` operator should work ?

any solution, advise would be much appreciated.

### Sample Data:

[image]

```
Hostname Aux Site OS Version
vlfox01 VCAD    CentOS 5.5
vlfox02 VCAD    RHEL 7.1
vlfox03 VCAD    RHEL 6.8
vlbrk01 brackn  RHEL 5.8
vlbrk02 brackn  SunOS 5.9
vlbrk03 brackn  RHEL 5.5
vlbrk04 brackn  RHEL 6.3
vlbrk05 brackn  RHEL  5.5
```

### Desired Data:

```
vlbrk01 brackn  RHEL 5.8
vlbrk02 brackn  SunOS 5.9
vlbrk03 brackn  RHEL 5.5
vlbrk04 brackn  RHEL 6.3
vlbrk05 brackn  RHEL  5.5
```

### Edit:

tried below and worked for now..

```
df2 = df1[(df1['OS Version'].str.contains(MATCH_PATT,  na=False)) & (df1['Aux Site'].str.contains('VCAD')==False)] [['Hostname', 'IP Address', 'Aux Site', 'OS Version']]
```

Comment: Your explanation isn't clear, could you please supply some data and expected output for this?

Comment: @cs95, i Just tried to clear the explanation, does it sounds good now.

Comment: Would you be able to provide 5-10 rows of dummy data and expected output please, I understand data a lot better than text :)

Comment: Updated the Data sample @cs95.

Comment: Thanks! Your code works for me, but I had to convert your regex into a raw string: `MATCH_PATT = r"AIX|CentOS|Fedora|RHEL|SunOS|SuSE|Ubuntu|(?<!\?)\?(?!\?)"`

Comment: Also `str.contains` also accepts `na=False` parameter.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the input @cs95.

Comment: @Emma, thanks for the idea, However i have multiple data variation and this is just sample data though otherwise it would be handy as you given.